# Google Sign In button does not work when popping VC

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, google-signin

I have two VC's in navigation controller - `SignInVC` and `SignUpVC`.

Both contains custom google sign in button.

When app launches, SignInVC appears first. When I push SignUpVC and go back the SignInVC in the following way

```
_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

I can't run sign in using button because the following

> Warning: Attempt to present SFSafariViewController: 0x157d47140 on
>   TestProject.SignUpViewController: 0x157d2f3b0 whose view is not in
>   the window hierarchy

error shows up in console.

It's worth to mention that I have also FB sign In button and it works in both view controllers. Also, button in SignUpVC works always, regardless of going back and forth in navigation

Is it something specific to Google Sign In?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because delegates were set in ViewDidLoad() method, which is not called when user gets back to previous controller in navigation stack.

this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GoogleManager.shared.delegate = self
}
```

solves the issue.